# I trying to upload file to server with use of EXT.NET 2.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, file-upload, ext.net

I Am Trying To Upload file to Server with help of EXT.NET Version 2.0

In My Case :
i am write under the

```
<ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUploadField1" runat="server" Width="300"><DirectEvents> 


</DirectEvents></ext:FileUploadField>
```

Give me error on `<FileSelected OnEvent="FileUploadField_FileSelected" IsUpload="true" />`
FileSelected are not available

My Code:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" />
        <ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUploadField1" runat="server" Width="300">
            <DirectEvents>
                <FileSelected OnEvent="FileUploadField_FileSelected" IsUpload="true" />
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:FileUploadField>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

My C# Code:
In this SaveAs option are not valid its generate error:

```
protected void FileUploadField_FileSelected(object sender, DirectEventArgs e)
    {
        this.FileUploadField1.SaveAs(@"D:\video1.mp4");
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Ext.Net" Namespace="Ext.Net" TagPrefix="ext" %>
<script runat="server">
    protected void FileUploadField_FileSelected(object sender, DirectEventArgs e) {
        if (this.FileUploadField1.HasFile)
        {
            HttpPostedFile file = FileUploadField1.PostedFile;
            file.SaveAs(@"d:\" + file.FileName);
        } 
    }
</script>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Ext.NET Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server">
        <ext:ResourceManager runat="server" SourceFormatting="True" ScriptMode="Debug" />
        <ext:FileUploadField ID="FileUploadField1" runat="server" Width="300">
            <DirectEvents>
                <Change OnEvent="FileUploadField_FileSelected" IsUpload="true"></Change>
            </DirectEvents>
        </ext:FileUploadField>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```